# Indoor mapping in iOS

Tags: ios, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I have map of my office room. I am trying to implement indoor mapping inside the office room for iOS. I watched the video from the WWDC2014 on Corelocation and indoor mapping. I also have the sample code from them. I am not sure what exactly they mean by "floor plan pixel". I have an image of the office and how can I use the following image to use as the floor plan pixel? I will really appreciate if somebody can guide me how to do or let me know if there are githubs or other resources are doing indoor mapping and tracking in iOS.

Thank you[image: It is the floor plan of my office room]

Comment: As far as I know your venue needs to be mapped by Apple for indoor location - you can't just do this yourself

Comment: Is it a good idea to use iBeacons to navigate through the room?If yes, How can I go on implementing it?

Comment: iBeacons have a range of about 15-100 feet and they are non-directional, so I would say no.  Precise indoor mapping is typically done with multiple WiFi base stations and using trilateration

Comment: @Rosh Did you downloaded FootPrint from Apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to apply for your venue to be mapped on Apple's Map Connect Website.  You will have to declare that you are the manager for the venue, then instructions will follow. This will involve you providing blueprints for the venue to Apple, locations of Wi-Fi base stations and (possibly) iBeacons. You will have to use Apple's specific app (that you find in the Appstore) to map the venue.  When all the process is done, you will be online: you should be able to see your venue in Apple maps and do whatever your need to do.

Having said that, Apple seems, still, focussed on venues that have at least one million visitors per year. If your venue is smaller you are stuck with iBeacons and your own implementation of a positioning / proximity algorithm.  Take a look at Open Tagger, as an example in Swift, it will give you an idea of the task and hopefully a very good starting point.

https://github.com/PaoloLongato/open-tagger/tree/github-master

Comment: Thanks @Eppilo. That's exactly what has happened to my project. They haven't added my venue to their map since it has less than 1 million visitor per year. I guess will have to wait for a lot longer before I will be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Well it depends.  If you only need your app to "react" to the user passing by  a set of points and you can install bacons, then it is not actually difficult to implement an algorithm similar to open tagger above and install an handful of beacons.  If you need a fully fledged indoor navigation it becomes a little more complicated to achieve.  In most cases I would argue that, if your location is not a large airport, stadium, shopping center or similar, then you really do not need proper navigation and room by room or area by area is enough (which makes a beacons installation a lot more viable).

Comment: I pretty much wanted to try the indoor mapping for getting hands-on experience on developing indoor mapping since it is pretty much new in apple. I already looked into iBeacons specially Estimote Beacons.  Thanks for enlighting about that.

Comment: The frustrating bit about Apple is that they won't let you read Wi-Fi base station RSSIs, so if you want to use Wi-Fi and not iBeacons you will have to wait until they relax the one million visitors constraint. Besides iBeacons there are alternatives that other companies, with SDKs, are providing (earth magnetic field distortion is a notable one).